# Ansible: perform shell script

Tags: ansible

This is my ansible snippet:

```
- name: Moves backup files into mssql location environment
      script: ./restore-backups.sh {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address|default(ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]) }}
      args:
        executable: bash
```

I'm trying to perform an script is located under home directory:

```
~ ls -lh
total 1.3M
-rw-r--r--. 1 vagrant vagrant  190 Nov  7 21:32 restore-backups.sh
```

Ansible is getting me:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access './restore-backups.sh'\nSearched in:\n\t/vagrant/provisioning/files/./restore-backups.sh\n\t/vagrant/provisioning/./restore-backups.sh\n\t/vagrant/provisioning/files/./restore-backups.sh\n\t/vagrant/provisioning/./restore-backups.sh on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

I don't quite figure out what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is looking for `/vagrant/provisioning/./restore-backups.sh`. You don't need to use `./` to execute script and you can set the directory of your script with `chdir` parameter.
Try as below

```yaml
- name: Moves backup files into mssql location environment
  script: restore-backups.sh {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address|default(ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]) }}
    chdir: /home/vagrant #Home vagrant path
    args:
        executable: bash
```

Link to documentation of `script` module, there are some examples how use it.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html